# Can't run Marble QML examples

Tags: qt, qml, kde-plasma, marble

I am trying to work with [KDE Marble](https://invent.kde.org/education/marble) and I see [this document](https://marble.kde.org/dev-intro.php).

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import org.kde.marble 0.20

MarbleWidget {
  projection: "Mercator"
  mapThemeId: "earth/openstreetmap/openstreetmap.dgml"
}
```

> QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
>
> qt.qpa.qgnomeplatform.theme: The desktop style for QtQuick Controls 2
> applications is not available on the system (qqc2-desktop-style).
>
> The application may look broken. QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load
> component qrc:/main.qml:4:1: module "org.kde.marble" is not installed

I also can't run and test [examples/qml/](https://invent.kde.org/education/marble/-/tree/master/examples/qml).

I use:

- Fedora 38
- Qt 5.15.10

I could build and install Marble, and its widgets work correctly, but I can't try its QML example.

Comment: Are you linking your app with the marble libraries? From the examples, it looks like you may need to link with `marbledeclarative`.

Comment: @JarMan  thanks for your comment,  I didn't understand, could you show me in one example? I can run widget examples but I can't run QML.

Comment: In your CMakeFiles.txt, do you have something like this: `target_link_libraries(${TARGET} marblewidget marbledeclarative)`

Comment: @JarMan I test it , but adding marbledeclarative didnt fix it , I try in both qmake and cmake.I still get `qrc:/main.qml:4:1: module "org.kde.marble" is not installed`.

Comment: @JarMan I think this might be relate to installation of marble from [this doc](https://marble.kde.org/sources.php) they said `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DWITH_KF5=TRUE -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ~/marble/sources` but as I check there is no `MarbleQuickItem.h` file how should we install it correctly to enable qml too?